# How to update my application for iOS 6 or 6.1 compatibility?

Tags: iphone, ios6, ios-simulator

I developed an application a year ago against iOS 5.1. Now when I run the app on iOS 6 or 6.1, it doesn't work. Even if I select the iOS 6 simulator and build the app, the app builds, but stops when I try to run it. If I select the iOS 5.1 simulator, it works. 
My Xcode version is 4.5.2. I set my deployment on 6.0 but still it is not running on 6.0.

This is happing first time with me. I am stuck on this stag from last 2 days.

Any idea how could I become with the latest iOS version?

Comment: You'll need to run it in the 6.0 emulator/debugger and see where and why it crashes.

Comment: It is not crashing. I try to run it on 6.0 simulator but it is not running in simulator 6.0 but runs good in 5.1

Comment: Even it is not going in my AppDelegate while running in iOS6.0

Comment: check your application deployment Taget.

Comment: what sort of an error you are facing while trying to run it in simulator 6.0?

Comment: Deployment target means the minimum support of iOS. In my case it is 5.0 but if i set deployment target to 6.0 then it hides the option of simulator 5.1 and also not running in 6.0. I already tried these things

Comment: @ForamMukundShah it is giving no error at all. When i run my app in iOS6 simulator then it builds the app, gives msg "Build Succeeded" but does not launch application on simulator

Comment: what version of xcode you are using?

Comment: @ForamMukundShah 4.5.2

Comment: just try to close xcode and restart it.may be it will work...

Comment: @Mashhadi You'll need to update the question with more information or it will likely be closed. Not everyone reads all the comments to get information that should be in the question.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ok let me edit

Comment: If your code perfectly runs on simulator 5 & if you have already tried with restarting xcode, then you need to upgrade your xcode.

Comment: @ForamMukundShah yes I tried all these things. Now I'll try your suggestion to update my xcode thanx

Comment: people vote down the question very fastly but nobody gives any good answer. @ForamMukundShah only tried to help me

Comment: Change your app deployment target to 4.3 or whatever. If its set to default its picking ios6

Comment: can you give the error message?

Comment: No error msg @amar and in vain with development target 4.3

Comment: Hey all you guys! If you don't have the answer of any question please just don't down vote it.

Comment: @UmairAamir The downvote button says that a downvote can mean that the question in itself was unclear. Without reading through the following 10 or so comments, it originally was.

Comment: If it took around 1.5 hrs and 15 odd comments for someone to fully understand the question, then it deserved to get downvoted and closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got your problem... I also faced this kind of problem when I need to test an application and I had not it provisioning profiles to install that app on my device. So I changed its bundle Identifier with some other App for which I had the provisioning profiles and tested that but when I ran the other app whose profiles I used, was showing same behavior as you are looking with your App. 
So I did the following and it solved my problem.

Just delete the App from your iPhone or iOS Simulator and also double check that if there is not any other App Installed with the same bundle Identifier.

Comment: Seems like possible solution. +1.